# How should the grant type of an oauth2 access token be preserved after refreshing it using refresh grant?

Tags: oauth2, access-token

Let's say I got an access token of the "authorization code" grant type. After the expiration of it, I would refresh it using the refresh grant. Then I'll get a new token. Is the grant type of the new token still the same as the "authorization code" or "refresh grant"?

Should an authorization server preserve the grant type history for future use? If not, how to know what is the original grant type of the token? Is there a standard way? I checked multiple specifications (rfc6750, rfc7662, rfc6749) and I could not find any info related to it.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you referring to refresh tokens?

Comment: @Sir Muffington, I'm referring to access tokens.

Comment: You speak of the "grant type of a token", but `grant_type` is a parameter of the token _request_ (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-4.1.3), not of the token itself (it does not occur in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.html#section-4.1.4). A token refresh request must have `grant_type=refresh_token`, but again, the refreshed token itself contains no `grant_type`.